# linq `from` clauses between generic and non-generic collections?

Tags: c#, linq

I've these linq `from` clauses in a sentence:

```
IEnumerable<T> collection = //...;
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesToFlat = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(FlattenAttribute)));

var accessorFieldsbyLevel = from element in collection
                            from property in propertiesToFlat
                            from internalField in (IEnumerable<object>)(typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(element))
                            //...
```

This sentence compiles. However I need to substitute the next `from` clause:

```
from internalField in (IEnumerable<object>)(typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(element))
```

by this one:

```
from internalField in (IEnumerable)(typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(element))
```

So, I'm only changing `(IEnumerable<object>)` cast by this other one `(IEnumerable)`.

Then the compiler tells me:

> Error 1   An expression of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

I've absolutly no idea what's happening.
What's wrong here?

**[EDIT]**

I suppose the problem is because `collection` and `propertiesToFlat` are a generic collections, I'm trying to set a `from` clause with a non-generic `IEnumerable`.

How could I solve that?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to substitute?

Comment: Sometimes the collection is of `enum`-like types. So, when I try to cast it crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, LINQ contains *very* few operations which work on non-generic collections. There's no `Enumerable.Where(IEnumerable, ...)` for example - only `Enumerable.Where<T>(IEnumerable<T>, ...)`.

The simplest way to fix this is to use an *explicitly typed range variable* in your query, which will insert a call to `Enumerable.Cast<T>(IEnumerable)`:

```
from object internalField in (IEnumerable)(typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(element))
```

That's equivalent to:

```
from internalField in 
    ((IEnumerable)(typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(element))
    .Cast<object>()
```

Comment: Even if the "`object` types" are `enum` types?

Comment: @Jordi: Well that will end up boxing them - if you've got a better type to use as the range variable type, then yes, you should use that.